# Insert statement in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my statement which I am using.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO store (shop_id, shop_index, items) VALUES ('$shop_id','65535','4')";
$this->db->query($sql);
return shop_st;
```

shop_st is the primary key which is auto incremented and I want to return it. I want to know whether my query is correct or wrong . Please let me know if I am going wrong.

Comment: To know whether your query is right or wrong you have to execute it

Comment: don't you get an error here `return shop_st`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of codeigniter's syntax, if you enable the `database` helper, you can do something like this:

```
$data = array(
   'shop_st' => NULL,
   'shop_id' => $shop_id ,
   'shop_index' => '65535' ,
   'items' => '4'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
```

I don't think there's anything more 'right' than your method, except you can do this.

```
return $this->db->insert_id(); //shop_st
```

which will get you your last inserted id.

This answer is just to raise make you aware of codeigniter's built in helpers.

The database helper can be [found here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/).

Comment: Thanks Alex . I want to return shop_st . I don't want it to return me shop_id.

Comment: @user3270582 the `insert_id` will be the auto incremented primary key. So this will be the one you're looking for. (`shop_st`)

Comment: Include the `database` helper and then use `return $this->db->insert_id();` and you'll have your answer :) @user3270582

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$data = array(
   'shop_st' => NULL,
   'shop_id' => $shop_id ,
   'shop_index' => '65535' ,
   'items' => '4'
);
function insertShop($data)
{
$res=$this->db->insert('store', $data)
if($res)
{
    return $res;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

---

You will have to use the insert_id helper function (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO store (shop_id, shop_index, items) VALUES ('$shop_id','65535','4')";
$this->db->query($sql);
return $this->db->insert_id();
```